# Best Site for Makerbot, 3D printing, etc?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Getting a makerbot at work, therefore lots of questions anticipated!

Any clue which SE might be best?

Comment: Depends on what the nature of the question is.  Can you give more details about the kinds of questions that you want to ask.

Comment: You could try [Robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @casperOne, my ignorance is pretty comprehensive, so there's no telling what I'll be clueless about at this time!

Comment: @MarkHarrison When you actually get the makerbot, and then have a better idea of the type of question you want to ask, that would be a better time to find out where to ask it.  By your own words, you don't know what you'll ask, and there's a number of different ways that you can approach makerbot, so we don't have much to help narrow it down for you at this time.

Comment: I think a more correct response would seem to be "there's not one at this time."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication) makes it through the proposal stage (and does better than [its predecessor](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22246/personal-manufacturing)), there likely isn't a good place for questions about Makerbot.

*Maybe* [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), but I'm not sure. It'd probably depend on the question.

Comment: Thanks Anna.  I'm active on Electrical Engineering; I don't think it's a good fit there.  I have similar doubts about Digital Fabrication;  I think the number of people who do CNC milling, etc, are going to be much smaller than the number of of people who get a 3D printer.  I imagine that as 3D printers pick up in popularity things will sort themselves out SE-wise.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Updating Anna's answer:

[Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/digital-fabrication) had little success.

Still, it seems there is a constant need for such a place, because its successor, [3D Printing and Rapid Prototyping](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing-and-rapid-prototyping) is currently in proposal stage.

I stumbled on this question searching for a similar place, and encourage all those who do to take a little time to back up this Area 51 proposal.

Answer (score 1):

[**3D Printing Stack Exchange**](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) is now up and running!

We're actually less than one day old - more like seven hours, actually - but the site is healthy and will hopefully enter public beta within a couple weeks. [The Area 51 description](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82438/3d-printing) is

> Beta Q&A site for the tools and applications of 3D printing.

We've already had one question about Makerbot, and there's now a [makerbot](/questions/tagged/makerbot) tag.